# Unbind - Remove - Kill a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to "unbind" a jQuery plugin from a jquery selector?

Comment: It depends on the plugin

Comment: So there is no native jquery function. That's bad...

Comment: @fuSi0N - That's not bad, it depends on the plugin, jQuery core didn't do whatever effect you want to reverse...the plugin you got did.  If you included which plugin you're using, there's *probably* a way of reversing it.  If not it's the plugin's fault really.

Comment: I don't know how jQuery could anticipate what each plugin is going to do. One solution may be to cache a pre-plugin `.clone()` of the element(s) that you could revert back to if/when needed (assuming the plugin doesn't have "undo" capability).

Comment: @Nick i need to disable and re-enable AutoSuggest jQuery plugin for an input. http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can unbind the plugin name from the jQuery prototype object with delete:

```
delete $.fn.pluginName;
```

This doesn't affect already initialized plugin instances though.

Comment: so how can we unbind the plugin after initialization?

Comment: Plugins usually provide a method of destroying themselves, eg. if you look at jQuery UI, they provide the 'destroy' method, so you can do eg: `$('selector').sortable('destroy');` But there is no uniform way to do this, as the plugin has to run specific piece of code to clean up after itself, and jQuery can't do that for you.

Answer (score 5):

Generally no.

The plugin typically makes changes to the elements that you apply it to. Sometimes those can simply be undone by removing the attributes or unbinding the events that the plugin added, but the plugin would need to provide this functionality, or you would have to know exactly what to remove.

Sometimes plugins overwrite information so that you can't undo it without knowing what the information was before the plugin was applied.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selector").unbind().removeData();
```