# jQuery: Use a plugin on a page pulled in via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm building a simple AJAX driven website (because of the audience, it's okay to do this) where pages are pulled in based on the anchor etc. Simple enough.

However, one of the pages I want to pull in should have a slideshow on it. Once the call is successful and the page appears, the plugin isn't working.

Do I have to re-initialize the plugins I want to use on a page that's dynamically pulled in?

I can't show any code right now but in theory, what would the best practice be to use plugins and re-init JS code on dynamic pages?

I usually have all my script in one jquery.scripts.js file in the head of the main index page. Do these scripts need to be on the separate pages themselves?

Many thanks!
Michael.

```
$('#logo a').click(function() {

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/test.html",
        data: '', 
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){

            if(parseInt(data)!=0) {

                $('#cycle').html(data);

                $("#cycle").cycle({

                    fx:         'fade',
                    //easing:   'easeOutExpo',
                    speed:      3000, 
                    //timeout:  0, 
                    //next:     '#cycle-next', 
                    //prev:     '#cycle-prev'

                });

            }

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

This code executes the call, loads the page, but does not re-init the plugin. It does nothing, and there are no errors. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is after you retrieved the ajax page, insert it into your website and when that is done you can initialize the slideshow.

so basically:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#target').html(data);
        $('#target .slideshow').slideshow();
    }
});

<div id="#target">
    <div class="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've made an edit my post to show what I have tried in light of this. It's still not working, but without errors.

Comment: You might have to put an extra element inside #cycle and then use the cycle plugin on that so you don't initialize it twice on the same element.

Comment: Hi, jeffreydev, you're right. It's weird. On my <ul> I was inserting the <li> tags only. It seems that I needed to replace the whole thing by wrapping another tag around this and then doing it that way. Either way it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether the cycle plugin has been previously initialized before running the $.ajax command. If it been, then you'll need to destroy the cycle slideshow and re-initialize it.

```
success:function(data){
    if(parseInt(data)!=0) {
        $('#cycle').html(data);
        $('#cycle').cycle('destroy');
        $("#cycle").cycle({
            fx:'fade',
            //easing:'easeOutExpo',
            speed:3000,
            //timeout:0,
            //next:'#cycle-next',
            //prev:'#cycle-prev'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, that's an interesting point. yes, it was initialised before too. 

Is that 'destroy' argument specific to cycle or is it a global jQuery method?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Destroy is part of the cycle plugin. See http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html for details.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this article helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502468/unbind-remove-kill-a-jquery-plugin

Sorry you didn't get the initial answer point, but I gave you two upvotes! Thanks again.