# Removing jQuery object from div

Tags: jquery, html, qr-code

I may have the wrong wording for this, but what I have done is used the following jQuery library to implement a QR reader using HTML5 and webRTC.

[HTML5 QR Reader](https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode/wiki)

I have this in a modal, and when the modal closes I would like to be able to stop using the webcam as well as stop trying to interpret QR codes.

So I've tried a few things outlined in this code snippet:

```
$("#qrReader_modal").on('hidden', function(){ 
    // Pausing the actual video element
    $("#html5_qrcode_video").pause();

    // Removing all elements in the div the qr reader was attached to
    $("#reader").empty();
});
```

However, neither works.

In the first case, it continues to use my camera, and the library continues to try and read a QR code.

In the second case, the div is correctly emptied, but the library then starts to throw read errors, and the webcam is still trying to capture video.

I would use the unbind function, but I didn't use bind to attach the html5_qrcode_reader. See here:

```
$("#reader").html5_qrcode(function(data){...});
```

So my question is what is the proper way to remove the html5_qrcode from the $("#reader") div

Comment: have you tried remove() ?

Comment: Just did. Gave me the same result as the second case. I continue to get read errors from the library and it appears the webcam is still being used. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: The plugin would need to provide this functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502468/unbind-remove-kill-a-jquery-plugin

Comment: Upsetting, but I guess you are correct. Thanks for the info

Comment: Did you ever resolved this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: It must be provided by the plugin. I've submitted the issue for one here: https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `html5_qrcode_stop()` function, which turns off the timer.
See implementation https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode/blob/master/src/html5-qrcode.js#L70