# QR code scanner with sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, qr-code

I need to open a qrcode scanner on a button click. below given is my code,

```
       var popup = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {

            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            width: 400,
            height: 450,

           items: [ {
                    html: '<div id="reader" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>'
                },]});

        Ext.Viewport.add(popup);
        popup.show({
            type: 'pop',
            isComponent: true
        });

        jQuery('#reader').html5_qrcode(
                function (data) {
                    var encoded = {
                        text: data,
                        format: 'TEXT_TYPE',
                        cancelled: false,
                        success: '200'
                    }
                    onSuccess(encoded);
                },
                function (error) {
                    //show read errors 
                },
                function (videoError) {
                    //the video stream could be opened
                }
        );
```

So this code works perfectly in desktop while fails in IOS and Android devices (Even camera is not opening!). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How can you conform this is working on desktop because as you said its supposed to open camera.

did you debug your code on device. ? why you using jquery for event handling ?

use Error handling like (try catch) get to know about the error if any.

Please go to below link some other has already been in same problem..

[Removing jQuery object from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846976/removing-jquery-object-from-div)

Comment: I used an external usb camera in desktop and found working, thats why I said like that. Also I put the above code in try-catch, but it doesn't made any change in the output.